# Object htmldivelement doesn't click on IE11

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

Will go to the school page and click on the like button. I'm going to the page object `htmldivelement` feature does not click the button. My commands are running with IE10, but it doesn't work with IE11.

```
Set hIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")   
hURL = "http://mukerremalikayanilkokulu.meb.k12.tr/icerikler/eglen-dusun-bul_6506730.html"

With hIE
    .Navigate hURL
    .Visible = True

    Do While hIE.Busy
    Loop
End With

Set haberss = hIE.document.getElementsByClassName("begen")
For Each haberbb In haberss
    If haberbb = "begen" Then
        Do While hIE.Busy
        Loop
        haberbb.Click
        Set hIE = hIE.Quit
        Exit For
    Else
        Do While hIE.Busy
        Loop
        haberbb.Click
        Set hIE = hIE.Quit
        Exit For
    End If
```

The `haberbb` button works on IE10, but on IE11 it does not work.

Comment: Note that your `If` statement `If haberbb = "begen" Then`  doesn't make any sense. It runs exactly the same code on `Then` as on `Else`!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware of my mistake. But I did it this way to see if they clicked positively or negatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know if that is functional or needs some form of login. I cannot manually click like.

Here are 3 code ways:

```
Ie.document.querySelector(".begen").click

Ie.document.querySelector(".begen").FireEvent "OnClick"

Ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('.begen').click;"
```

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AttemptClick()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://mukerremalikayanilkokulu.meb.k12.tr/icerikler/eglen-dusun-bul_6506730.html"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.querySelector(".begen").FireEvent "onclick"
        .document.querySelector(".begen").Click
        .document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('.begen').click();"
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try and inform you at the first opportunity

Comment: I try to click the like button and I can click it manually, than I try to run the @QHarr code and find that it is also working on my side with IE 11. Here is the testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/gJyYJMcS/45.gif

Comment: Thank you. "querySelector" has solved my problem. Thanks for learning something new. Thanks again.

Comment: Dear Qharr , When I clicked the button, they did it with a "like" increase. What I want to do is increase by 10 when I click. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: if you want to do 10 clicks then put the .click line instead of a for loop which runs from 1 to 10.

Comment: When I press the like button, the number is increasing. but when I press a second time, the number doesn't increase. I think there is a case about the script. if I can solve it for - next cycle solves my job as you said.

Comment: Can you manually increase it more than once? I suspect the page is designed to prevent someone sock-puppet like voting.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to QHarr's answer, your `Do While...Loop` isn't quite right.

1. You should do something in the loop, otherwise you are just going to spike the CPU usage. You should at least add a `DoEvents` in between to allow windows to process other programs/messages.
2. It doesn't look like you are waiting for the page load to complete.  Try adding `Or ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE` to the loop condition.

Putting it together, the loop should look like:

```
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE ' = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Here are some other references that might help:

[Failproof Wait for IE to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299134/failproof-wait-for-ie-to-load)

[How to wait for the page to load after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455109/how-to-wait-for-the-page-to-load-after-click)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try and inform you at the first opportunity

Comment: Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))  this command I think hope yet

Comment: I heard "ready state" doesn't work at "i11". it actually changed. :) worked very nice. Thank you too.